# Google Maps not showing up in my app

Tags: android, google-maps, google-directions-api

I receive the following map after I click the get directions button.

[Google Map with no detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NR5b.png)

[image: Map before Click]

[image: Map After Click]

I have already verified that the origin and destination are correct, but I cannot figure out why nothing appears.

I am using Google Direction library from https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-GoogleDirectionLibrary

Below is my code and all related files:

Gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.akexorcist:googledirectionlibrary:1.0.5'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Directions.java

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.akexorcist.googledirection.DirectionCallback;
import com.akexorcist.googledirection.GoogleDirection;
import com.akexorcist.googledirection.constant.TransportMode;
import com.akexorcist.googledirection.model.Direction;
import com.akexorcist.googledirection.model.Route;
import com.akexorcist.googledirection.util.DirectionConverter;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Directions extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
                                View.OnClickListener, DirectionCallback
{
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private LatLng origin = new LatLng(29.572813, -97.984900);
    private LatLng destination;
    private Button get_directions_btn;
    private String serverKey = <serverkey>;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_directions);


        // origin = new LatLng(29.572813, -97.984900);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        double destLatitude = bundle.getDouble("latitude");
        double destLongitude = bundle.getDouble("longitude");
        Log.d("Latitude", "Latitude is: " + destLatitude);
        Log.d("Longitude", "Longitude is:" + destLongitude);
        destination = new LatLng(destLatitude, destLongitude);

        get_directions_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.get_directions_btn);
        get_directions_btn.setOnClickListener(this);

        ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment)).getMapAsync(this);
    }

    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        this.googleMap = googleMap;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        if (id == R.id.get_directions_btn) {
            requestDirection();

        }
    }

    public void requestDirection() {
        Log.d("RequestOrigin", "Origin inside request: " + origin);
        Log.d("RequestDestination", "Destination inside request: " + destination);
        Snackbar.make(get_directions_btn, "Direction Requesting...", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        GoogleDirection.withServerKey(serverKey)
                .from(origin)
                .to(destination)
                .transportMode(TransportMode.DRIVING)
                .execute(this);
    }

    public void onDirectionSuccess(Direction direction, String rawBody) {
        Log.d("Status","Direction Status is:" +direction.getStatus());
        Snackbar.make(get_directions_btn, "Success with status : " + direction.getStatus(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (direction.isOK()) {
            Route route = direction.getRouteList().get(0);
            Log.d("Route ", "Route is: " + route);

            Log.d("Origin Marker", "Origin Marker: " + origin);
            Log.d("Destination Marker", "Destination Marker: " + destination);
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(origin));
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(destination));

            ArrayList<LatLng> directionPositionList = route.getLegList().get(0).getDirectionPoint();
            googleMap.addPolyline(DirectionConverter.createPolyline(this, directionPositionList, 5, Color.RED));
            setCameraWithCoordinationBounds(route);

            get_directions_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
        else{
            Log.d("Status","Direction Status is:" +direction.getStatus());
            Snackbar.make(get_directions_btn, direction.getStatus(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

        public void onDirectionFailure(Throwable t) {
            Snackbar.make(get_directions_btn, t.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    private void setCameraWithCoordinationBounds(Route route) {
        LatLng southwest = route.getBound().getSouthwestCoordination().getCoordination();
        LatLng northeast = route.getBound().getNortheastCoordination().getCoordination();
        LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds(southwest, northeast);
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 100));
    }
}
```

XML layout: activity_directions

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_directions"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Directions">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MapActivity" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/get_directions_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Get Directions" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: have you added a google API key yet?

Comment: @KevinAdhitama Yes, I have a key for both the google maps api and google directions api. I added the google maps api to the google_maps_api.xml file that is generated.

Comment: make sure u the **Google Maps Android API** and **Google Maps Direction API** Enabled on your console. try to set **Application restrictions** on API_KEY setting into **none**, and if u put the key in google_maps_api.xml, make sure in both file (debug and release), and theres meta-data of geo apikey in your manifest

Comment: @KevinAdhitama I believe I have down all of those steps. Could there perhaps be another reason?

Comment: if you cant put the marker inside your maps, the reason it must be came from google api key

Comment: @KevinAdhitama so do I need two keys? One for the maps and one for the directions library I’m using? If so where do I put both of them?

Comment: no, just one key needed, but enabled both of the api

Comment: @KevinAdhitama sorry for asking so many questions but I’m still learning. Will I need to create my own map activity or does the file Directions.java create the map for me?

Comment: no, you can do it in just one activity

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/RO48q

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enabled the **Google Maps Android API** and **Google Maps Direction API** in https://console.developers.google.com

[image: if not yet u can try to enabled api]

your api key will be on **Credentials** tab.

also make sure theres a meta-data tag inside your manifest, look like this:

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="YOUR_KEY" />
```

and heres some documentation for you https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start

EDIT :

maybe it happens to be your emulator isnt using Google API target, try to install another emulator that support Google API

here's some picture
[image]

Comment: I still seem to be getting the same results. I followed the steps, but nothing seemed to change. Is there any other steps needed to set up a map besides what was in the documentation?

Comment: Is there a possibility that it doesn’t work on the emulator I’m using?

Comment: have you put uses permission internet and access fine location on manifest?

Comment: Yes, along with the location permissions (coarse and fine)

Comment: give it a try in actual device?

Comment: i try it on my own device

Comment: it does maybe, emulator is just like the real device, have u try to open the browser on emulator? to make sure the emulator have an internet connection

Comment: I opened the actual google maps on the emulator and it worked so I think the internet is fine

Comment: I already run a version of marshmallow with google APIs. Would installing another one help?

Comment: okay, can you check on emulator settings (three dots on emulator menu) ? can u make sure openGL ES Rendered is enabled?

Comment: I'm having trouble finding where the emulator settings are. Are they on the emulator or inside android studio?

Comment: It has Autodetect based on host(default)

Comment: In the fragment I included I have tools:context=".MapsActivity". Do i need to create a maps activity for that? I'm confused on why the example shows it.

Comment: no, thats no need to do that.
how about you try to add **new -> activity -> gallery -> Google Maps Activity**, and if it works well, then the code you made before had a problem

Comment: The google maps activity also showed up as gray. I tried redoing the key also. I have no clue why this is going on.